# What is the SQL equivalent of COUNTIF?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to count the number of times a specific filter is used given its number of occurrences in a URL parameter. I have the URL parameter as a column. Here is a sample row result:

```
"lat"=>"28.5383355", "lng"=>"-81.37923649999999", "near"=>"Orlando, FL", "end_period"=>"05/08/2016", "place_input"=>"Orlando, Florida", "capacity_max"=>"100", "capacity_min"=>"7", "package_type"=>"bareboat", "start_period"=>"05/08/2016"
```

How would I go about counting the number of occurrences of e.g `"lat"`? I tried using a wildcard, but SQL returned the following error message:

```
operator does not exist: hstore ~~ unknown
  Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Position: 50
```

Hope somebody is able to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

another way to do this is

```
select sum( integer(url ? 'lat') ) from a_table
```

This form can be useful if you have several statistics you want to compute.

Comment: Even better! That is exactly what I wanted to do.

Answer (score 1):

Use the operator [`hstore ? text`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/hstore.html) which means *does hstore contain key?*

```
select count(*)
from a_table
where url ? 'lat';
```